# Error while vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I get the following error while doing a vagrant up :

```
$ vagrant up
D:/Jumbo/vagrants/endeca_vagrants/Vagrantfile:27:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `host'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:479:in `hook'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:728:in `unload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/bin/vagrant:141:in `ensure in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.5/bin/vagrant:141:in `<main>'
```

The contents of my Vagrant file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Copyright 2012, Javelin Group

require 'yaml'
current_dir    = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
configs        = YAML.load_file("#{current_dir}/config.yaml")
vagrant_config = configs['configs'][ENV['USER']]

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "D:/Jumbo/JumboDoc/endecavagrant/endeca.box"

    # Boot with a GUI so you can see the screen. (Default is headless)
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.gui = false
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 4096]
      v.name = "Jumbo Endeca VM"
    end

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8006, host: 8006, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8888, host: 8888, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network(:private_network, ip: "192.168.50.3", virtualbox__intnet: "intnet")

    # maps workstation kattle ETL folder to the vm folder
    config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrant_config['etl_dir']}", "/usr/local/endeca-deployment/development/etl"
    config.vm.network(:private_network, ip: "192.168.50.3", virtualbox__intnet: "intnet")
    # maps workstation endeca custom app config folder to the vm folder
    config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrant_config['app_config']}", "/usr/local/endeca-deployment/development/custom-script"

    config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrant_config['pipelines']}", "/usr/local/endeca-deployment/development/config/pipelines"
    config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrant_config['templates']}", "/usr/local/endeca-deployment/development/cartridge_templates"
    config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrant_config['report_templates']}", "/usr/local/endeca-deployment/development/report_templates"

end
```

I have tried updating the version of oracle vm virtual box.Also vagrant 1.9.4 works with the same file on other systems.I also tried to empty my space in C: drive. But did not get a solution. How can I fix this ? Please help.

Comment: Which one is line 27?

Comment: @axiac line 27 is : - 

config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrant_config['etl_dir']}", "/usr/local/endeca-deployment/development/etl"

I tried commenting this line but the same error persisted.

Comment: The error message says very clear: `nil` does not have the `[]` method. Obviously `vagrant_config` is `nil` and if you comment line 27 you get the same error on the next line that attempts to access it.

Comment: @axiac thanks a lot, that did the trick !!! It was not finding the user from environment.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that it was not finding the user from environment. That is why vagrant_configs was nil.Thanks to @axiac.